# highlight a row in seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

Today I'm working on a heatmap inside a function. It's nothing too fancy: the heatmap shows a value for every district in my city and inside the function one of the arguments is `district_name`.

[image: heatmap]

I want my function to print this same heatmap, but that it highlights the selected district (preferably through bolded text).

My code is something like this:

```
def print_heatmap(district_name, df2):
    df2=df2[df2.t==7]
    pivot=pd.pivot_table(df2,values='return',index= 'district',columns= 't',aggfunc ='mean')

    sns.heatmap(pivot, annot=True, cmap=sns.cm.rocket_r,fmt='.2%',annot_kws={"size": 10})
```

So I need to access ax's values, so I can bold, say "Macul" if I enter `print_heatmap('Macul',df2)`. Is there any way I can do this?

What I tried was to use `mathtext` but for some reason I can't use bolding in this case:

```
pivot.index=pivot.index.str.replace(district_name,r"$\bf{{{}}}$".format(district_name)
```

But that brings:

```
ValueError: 
f{macul}$
^
Expected end of text (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to bold both the ticklabel AND the value in annot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is hard to do this explicitly in seaborn, you can instead though iterate through the texts in the axes (annot) and the ticklabels and set their properties to "highlight" a row.

Here is an example of this approach.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 1)
cmap = mpl.cm.Blues_r
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, annot=True, cmap=cmap)
# iterate through both the labels and the texts in the heatmap (ax.texts)
for lab, annot in zip(ax.get_yticklabels(), ax.texts):
    text =  lab.get_text()
    if text == '2': # lets highlight row 2
        # set the properties of the ticklabel
        lab.set_weight('bold')
        lab.set_size(20)
        lab.set_color('purple')
        # set the properties of the heatmap annot
        annot.set_weight('bold')
        annot.set_color('purple')
        annot.set_size(20)
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need. I'll be trying it and tell you if it works ! Thanks